# Error building an arbitrary Specflow Feature

Tags: c#, specflow

I've added a specflow feature to a project and the project won't build.

The errors I recieve are:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'CodeDom' does not exist in the namespace 'Absolute.Website.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\source\dot_net\BWO\src\Absolute.Website.System.Tests\test.feature.cs 17  13  Absolute.Website.System.Tests
>
> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'Runtime' does not exist in the namespace 'Absolute.Website.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\source\dot_net\BWO\src\Absolute.Website.System.Tests\test.feature.cs 18  13  Absolute.Website.System.Tests

The problem seems to lie in the auto generated test.feature.cs file with these two lines:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "1.6.1.0")]
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
```

I have added a reference to the system assembly and can't figure out what could be causing the build error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem was due to the name of the namespace being in the form of xxxx.System.yyyy. When I renamed the assembly the problem to remove the xxxx.System.yyyy patern the project built.

Comment: I had an error on the same 2 lines.  My stupid mistake was that I copied an existing feature file, changed all the scenarios, but neglected to change the text at the top, `Feature: My Feature`

Comment: I also had named my test project `Test.System.xxx` which caused this weird coliision. Changing the root namespace did the trick although it does seem like a bug in the generated code.